# Calling language in babel through class options

Tags: babel, documentclass-writing, class-options

I'm writing a thesis class that should be bilingual, and the languages should be user inputted - one as primary and the other as secondary.

Because of the document structure, parts of the document are in primary language and other parts in the secondary. As an example there is an abstract for each language.

My difficulty has been passing the languages as options. I've tried `\PassOptionsToPackage` but it didn't seemed to work, so I've bypassed this with if statements, as shown:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{bilang-thesis}
\newif\if@portuguese
\newif\if@english
\DeclareOption{portuguese}{\@portuguesetrue\@englishfalse}
\DeclareOption{english}{\@portuguesefalse\@englishtrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[12pt]{book}
\if@portuguese
    \RequirePackage[english,main=portuguese]{babel}
\else
    \RequirePackage[portuguese,main=english]{babel}
\fi
```

The structure of the thesis is defined by the class. This means that blocks of text are automated for the intended sections, labels like section names are added accordingly to the specified languages through the `\addto\captions` command. In the following code I've defined two commands, one to structure the abstract, and the other to print it.

```
\newcommand*\shortabstract[2]{%
    \chapter*{\abstractname}%
    \label{cha:\abstractname}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{cha:\abstractname}}%
    #1%
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%

    \noindent\textbf{\keywordscaption: } #2%
}
\newcommand*\makeabstract{%
    \clearpage%
    \if@portuguese
        \begin{otherlanguage}{portuguese}
            \shortabstract{\@abstract}{\@keywords}
        \end{otherlanguage}
        \cleardoublepage
        \begin{otherlanguage}{english}
            \shortabstract{\@altabstract}{\@altkeywords}
        \end{otherlanguage}
        \cleardoublepage
    \else
        \begin{otherlanguage}{english}
            \shortabstract{\@abstract}{\@keywords}
        \end{otherlanguage}
        \cleardoublepage
        \begin{otherlanguage}{portuguese}
            \shortabstract{\@altabstract}{\@altkeywords}
        \end{otherlanguage}
        \cleardoublepage
    \fi
}
```

First command is just to declutter the second, because I can't get to call languages as keys or definitions, like `\@firstlang`, and have to use the ifs to call different `\begin{otherlanguage}` environments. When I've tried, babel throws an error that the language isn't defined.

So what I'm looking for is to understand how can one pass languages as commands, like first lang, second lang, in these babel environments.

Ultimately would like to solve the languages as options, and define multilingual commands, similar to the `\addto\captions` but for bigger chunks of text.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I was using `\def\@firstlang{firstlang}` to define the languages commands, but as Ulrike Fischer suggested one can simply define `\newcommand\firstlang {english}`. As this first question is answered, I've changed the topic to the main intended question.

How to pass languages as options from class, bearing that languages are unknown.

**MWE**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{bilang-thesis}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
 \SetupKeyvalOptions{%
   family=BL,
   prefix=BL@,
   }

\DeclareStringOption[firstlang,secondlang]{languages}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\PassOptionsToPackage{\BL@languages}{babel}
\RequirePackage{babel}
```

I believe this works, but how can then one select the languages?

Comment: Instead of showing your work-arounds you should better show what didn't work for you. E.g. `\newcommand\firstlang {english}` and then `\begin{otherlanguage}{\firstlang}` works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, I know should have done that, but I've deleted the code and was having a hard time rewriting it. I am trying to pass the options from loading the class, so the languages are in a way unknown `\documentclass[secondlang,firstlang]{bilang-thesis}`. For the languages I was using `\def\@firstlang{firstlang}`. With your suggestion I can define a command to select the languages such as `\languages{firstlang}{secondlang}` but I am wondering how to do it with the options.

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion doesn't work for me

Comment: is your babel up-to-date?

Comment: Apparently it is not. I am using overleaf, and babel was 3.12, just changed to 3.36, which is still not up to date

Comment: As an aside: don't use `main=` except if there is a real reason to do so, as explained in the manual.

Comment: @JavierBezos thank you. But actually there is, for some reason babel isn't assuming the last language as the main. Therefore the inclusion of `main=`